# scoped_lock() - an RAII implementation using pthread

Tags: c++, error-handling, pthreads, c++03, raii

I have a socket shared between 4 threads and I wanted to use the *RAII* principle for acquiring and releasing the mutex.

---

**The ground realities**

1. I am using the pthread library.
2. I cannot use Boost.
3. I cannot use anything newer than C++03.
4. I cannot use exceptions.

---

**The Background**

Instead of having to lock the mutex for the socket everytime before using it, and then unlocking the mutex right afterwards, I thought I could write a `scoped_lock()` which would lock the mutex, and once it goes out of scope, it would automatically unlock the mutex.

So, quite simply I do a lock in the constructor and an unlock in the destructor, as shown here.

```
ScopedLock::ScopedLock(pthread_mutex_t& mutex, int& errorCode)
: m_Mutex(mutex)
{
    errorCode = m_lock();
}

ScopedLock::~ScopedLock()
{
    errorCode = m_unlock();
}
```

where `m_lock()` and `m_unlock()` are quite simply two wrapper functions around the `pthread_mutex_lock()` and the `pthread_mutex_unlock()` functions respectively, with some additional tracelines/logging.

In this way, I would not have to write at least two unlock statements, one for the good case and one for the bad case (at least one, could be more bad-paths in some situations).

---

**The Problem**

The problem that I have bumped into and the thing that I don't like about this scheme is the destructor.

I have diligiently done for every function the error-handling, but from the destructor of this `ScopedLock()`, I cannot inform the caller about any errors that might be returned my `m_unlock()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fundamental problem with RAII, but in this case, you're in luck. `pthread_unlock` only fails if you set up the mutex wrong (`EINVAL`) or if you're attempting to unlock an error checking mutex from a thread that doesn't own it (`EPERM`). These errors are indications of bugs in your code, not runtime errors that you should be taking into account. `assert`ing `errorCode==0` is a reasonable strategy in this case.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Finally someone paid attention `＼(^o^)／`.

Comment: I was ignoring the errors till now, but I will add an `assert()` there. I just wonder now then how C++ libraries/applications then do error-handling when they face such a situation? *Cannot* return errors from the destructor, *should not* throw exceptions from the destructor and some third option we have not.

Comment: @JoeyMallone There are cases where you can have legit runtime errors in cleanup code (e.g., `close()` for closing files or a `write_closing_html_tag()`). Personally I use my own, currently private, alternative to RAII/exceptions where signalling errors from automated cleanup code is possible, easy & fast. Otherwise, if you need to handle errors in cleanup code, you can do it the old-fashion way. Not in a dtor, but in regular code, and use control flow mechanisms like `try`-`catch`/`goto` to make sure (the possibly failing) cleanup code is never skipped even if it isn't in a dtor.

Comment: @JoeyMallone As for what C++ code usually does: most of what I've seen simply ignores such situations (e.g., errors in closing a file) or logs the error instead of signalling it to the caller. You can signal it to the caller, though, as long as you give up on RAII, at least for the resource whose cleanup may signal failure.

Comment: Ok. @Pskocik. Thanks for the explanation and the hints. `:)`